# Obtain other Google Workspace accounts' Google Contacts using API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-people-api

I am superadmin of a Google Workspace. I would like to obtain Google Contacts of several accounts of interest. For example, `press@....org` and `donate@....org` accounts of my workspace (for anaylytics / backup / mailing list compilation).

What are the ways I can achieve this, regarding authorization? As a superadmin, can I [impersonate other users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65897777/google-contacts-are-not-showing-by-using-google-people-api) and access their Google Contacts via an API? Can [service accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665027/using-google-contacts-api-to-access-contacts-for-other-users-in-google-apps-doma) be used for this?

If anyone has an example or some advice on achieving this, it would be great :)

Thank you!

Comment: I cannot answer for accessing contacts as I have not tried. Google Workspace supports [Domain Wide Delegation of Authority](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation) which allows you to impersonate Workspace users via service accounts.

Comment: As you suggested, I set up a service account and enabled Domain Wide Delegation, but getting an error: `google.auth.exceptions.RefreshError: ('unauthorized_client: Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.', {'error': 'unauthorized_client', 'error_description': 'Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method, or client not authorized for any of the scopes requested.'})` :(

Comment: Using this Python code: `creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('my_service_account_key.json', scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly'] ).with_subject('vadim.kantorov@my.org'); print(googleapiclient.discovery.build('people', 'v1', credentials=creds).people().connections().list(resourceName='people/me', pageSize=10, personFields='names,emailAddresses').execute())`

Comment: Please add details to your post and not via comments. The error means that you did not set up Domain Wide Delegation correctly. However, test the API accessing a user's mailbox or other Workspace feature as I have not tested accessing a user's contacts to make sure DWD is set up correctly.

Comment: It ended up working! My mistake was that I actually had a few more extra unused scopes in the `from_service_account_file` call (and only had `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly` in the service account config). And I also found a tutorial for doing a similar thing in Apps Script: https://daubejb.medium.com/how-to-use-gcp-service-accounts-with-google-apps-script-projects-to-automate-actions-in-g-suite-7020a520bef7

If you feel like it, please add an answer with your advice of setting up Domain Wide Delegation (maybe paste a word on what it is), I will mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Google Workspace supports Domain Wide Delegation of Authority which allows you to impersonate Workspace users via service accounts.

Domain-wide delegation of authority grants third-party and internal applications access to your users' data.

This requires setup at Workspace and Cloud IAM for the service account.

[Perform Google Workspace domain-wide delegation of authority](https://developers.google.com/cloud-search/docs/guides/delegation)